# Vim color in gnome-terminal

Tags: vim, colors, vim-plugin, gnome-terminal

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this, nothing so far.
I installed vim, got the colorschemes, got a bunch of plugins (including guicolorscheme.vim), followed the steps on the wiki and the terminal does not display a single color.
When I turn :syntax on, I get things like this:

```
^[[38;5;130mset ^[[38;5;5mt_Co=256
^[[38;5;130mset ^[[38;5;5mt_AB=^[[48;5;%dm
^[[38;5;130mset ^[[38;5;5mt_AF=^[[38;5;%dm
```

Formerly:

```
set t_Co=256
set t_AB=^[[48;5;%dm
set t_AF=^[[38;5;%dm
```

Any ideas? I tried both in a normal gnome-terminal and guake, with the same results: plain monochromatic text. Not even a trace of the colorscheme either.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Seems I messed up with the config files (that or a broken install). I reinstalled, and just with guicolorscheme and set to 256 on the vimrc seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Broken install? What is the value of `$TERM`.

Comment: Colors show up normally outside vim?

Comment: What is the extension of the filename you used ?

Comment: @romainl TERM is xterm.

Comment: @cirosantilli yes. I tried the script provided on the wiki. all colors show up

Comment: @user2987828 it' the same no matter what extension

Comment: What does show this: stty -a

Comment: @romainl seems it was a broken install. so far, w/out any plugins the syntax highlight works. i'll see what happens when gradually adding them.

Comment: @user2987828 speed 38400 baud; rows 23; columns 79; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = M-^?; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke

Comment: It seems that this question should be marked as resolved. You could put your "edit" paragraph as an answer (possibly giving some more details) and accept it as an answer.